# PHPleague oauth2.0 Client Error when accessing with post request in access_token

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, access-token

I am currently working on a web feature which is the implementation of an oauth2 server via phpleague. I think I did well on the design of my server but I do not know why the client displays an error that I do not understand.

My client code:

```php
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$provider = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider([
    'clientId'                => '1',    // The client ID assigned to you by the provider
    'clientSecret'            => 'haha',    // The client password assigned to you by the provider
    'redirectUri'             => 'http://localhost:4444/callback.php',
    'urlAuthorize'            => 'http://localhost:1337/authorize',
    'urlAccessToken'          => 'http://localhost:1337/access_token',
    'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => 'https://service.example.com/resource'
]);

// If we don't have an authorization code then get one
if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {

    // Fetch the authorization URL from the provider; this returns the
    // urlAuthorize option and generates and applies any necessary parameters
    // (e.g. state).
    $authorizationUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl();

    // Get the state generated for you and store it to the session.
    $_SESSION['oauth2state'] = $provider->getState();

    // Redirect the user to the authorization URL.
    header('Location: ' . $authorizationUrl);
    exit;

// Check given state against previously stored one to mitigate CSRF attack
} elseif (empty($_GET['state']) || (isset($_SESSION['oauth2state']) && $_GET['state'] !== $_SESSION['oauth2state'])) {

    if (isset($_SESSION['oauth2state'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['oauth2state']);
    }

    exit('Invalid state');

} else {

    try {

        // Try to get an access token using the authorization code grant.
        $accessToken = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
            'code' => $_GET['code']
        ]);
    
        // We have an access token, which we may use in authenticated
        // requests against the service provider's API.
        echo 'Access Token: ' . $accessToken->getToken() . "<br>";
        echo 'Refresh Token: ' . $accessToken->getRefreshToken() . "<br>";
        echo 'Expired in: ' . $accessToken->getExpires() . "<br>";
        echo 'Already expired? ' . ($accessToken->hasExpired() ? 'expired' : 'not expired') . "<br>";

        // Using the access token, we may look up details about the
        // resource owner.
        $resourceOwner = $provider->getResourceOwner($accessToken);

        var_export($resourceOwner->toArray());

        // The provider provides a way to get an authenticated API request for
        // the service, using the access token; it returns an object conforming
        // to Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface.
        var_dump($access_token);

    } catch (\League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException $e) {

        // Failed to get the access token or user details.
        exit($e->getMessage());

    }

}
```

Error in callback when getAccessToken is called.

Here's the stack trace:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught UnexpectedValueException:
Failed to parse JSON response: 
Syntax error in /opt/lampp/htdocs/oauth2_client/vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php:645
Stack trace: 
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/oauth2_client/vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php(686): League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider->parseJson() 
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/oauth2_client/vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php(626): League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider->parseResponse() 
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/oauth2_client/vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php(537): League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider->getParsedResponse() 
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/oauth2_client/callback.php(43): League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider->getAccessToken()
#4 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/oauth2_client/vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php on line 645
```

I don't understand why i have this error...

Comment: The response coming back from the API is not JSON. Therefore it cannot be parsed as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the error. When i send request to my access_token i have notice error so when my client send post request and parse json it causes an error when parsing because it tries to parse the error into string directly which is not in json format